# Oracle: how to migrate a multiple-rows table with dynamic key-value columns into a table with a fixed column structure?

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, insert, grouping

Imagine the following scenario.

I have an Oracle database with a table which has dynamic key-value columns for a single grouping column named CODE:

```
-----------------------------------------
|    CODE     |    KEY    |    VALUE    |
-----------------------------------------
|   123456    |    name   |    Paul     |
|   123456    |   surname |    White    |
|   123456    |   nation  |   England   |
|   987654    |    name   |    Alan     |
|   987654    |   surname |    Ford     |
|   987654    |   nation  |   Ireland   |
-----------------------------------------
```

And I have another table with each of those column represented by the "KEY":

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    CODE     |    NAME    |    SURNAME    |    NATION    |  DYNAMICS  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|             |            |               |              |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My task is to write in the second table (with known column names) the datas stored in the first table.
In other words, I have to switch from a multiple rows table into a single row table.

My idea is to create also a new column named "DYNAMICS" in the second table with "unknown" columns, where we must concat every possible key-value not already mapped in each column like NAME, etc...

This is the must-have result:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    CODE     |    NAME    |    SURNAME    |    NATION    |  DYNAMICS  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   123456    |   Paul     |    White      |   England    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   987654    |   Alan     |     Ford      |   Ireland    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I do it in the proper way?

Comment: Anything that you have tried so far?

Comment: I tried to study some possible functions like pivot or xmlagg, but I have not found a useful solution since now, that's why I've asked here

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
with demo (code, key, value) as
     ( select 123456, 'name',     'Paul'    from dual union all
       select 123456, 'surname',  'White'   from dual union all
       select 123456, 'nation',   'England' from dual union all
       select 987654, 'name',     'Alan'    from dual union all
       select 987654, 'surname',  'Ford'    from dual union all
       select 987654, 'nation',   'Ireland' from dual )
   , persons as
     ( select distinct code, value as surname from demo
       where  key = 'surname' )
select per.code
     , fnm.value as firstname
     , per.surname
     , nat.value as nation
from   persons per
       left join demo fnm on fnm.code = per.code and fnm.key = 'name'
       left join demo nat on nat.code = per.code and nat.key = 'nation';

CODE       FIRSTNAME SURNAME NATION
---------- --------- ------- -------
123456     Paul      White   England
987654     Alan      Ford    Ireland
```

I couldn't see what you needed to do in the `DYNAMICS` column, though.

Comment: Thanks. The "DYNAMICS" column is thought to store every possible row that can't be stored in its own column on the other table. I know that's quite difficult to explain exactly what I need.